# How to Load .csproj file into .NET Core 3.0 using MSBuild NuGet

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, project

I have a very simple console project:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var project = new Project(
            "FishStory.csproj", 
            null, 
            null, 
            new ProjectCollection());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is a .NET Core 3.0 console application, and it has **Microsoft.Build (16.4.0)** NuGet package referenced.

The .csproj file `FishStory.csproj` is found (I don't get an exception that the .csproj is missing), but I do get the following error.

> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: 
>   'The imported project 
>   "C:\Users\vchel\source\repos\ForDave\ForDave\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found. 
>   Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Users\vchel\source\repos\ForDave\ForDave\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\vchel\source\repos\ForDave\ForDave\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\FishStory.csproj'

I'd expect that such a simple MSBuild test would "just work", but it seems like I'm missing something. What can I do to load this .csproj file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the NuGet package adds the necessary .dlls to use the Project object, but the various project types must have .target and .props files which are used when the Project .csproj is loaded.

To load my specific project, I had to add the following files to the output directory. I accomplished this by placing the files in my project and marking them as *Copy if Newer*.

I added the following files:

- Microsoft.Common.targets
- Microsoft.CSharp.targets
- Microsoft.NETFramework.props
- Microsoft.NETFramework.targets

In my case the .csproj is a MonoGame project, so I also had to add:

- MonoGame.Build.Tasks.dll (not sure if I needed this or not)
- MonoGame.common.props
- MonoGame/v3.0/MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets

To add these files so they are copied to the output folder:

1. Add the file to your project (for .NET Core you just have to add the file to the directory)
2. Right-click on the file in the **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties**
3. Set the **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy if newer**

I pulled the targets/props/.dll files from:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0

I am guessing that other project types (such as an Android Xamarin project) may require different .targets files, which can be found here if using Visual Studio 2019 Community:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin

Finally, I also had to manually add the NuGet Package **Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core**. Not sure why that wasn't automatically added when adding **Microsoft.Build**

[image: Solution Explorer Screenshot]

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildLocator.

Answer (score 1):

I have catched the same exception while I have tried to load a project targeted to netcore31 platform. 
But after that I have installed

- Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core(16.5.0)
- Microsoft.Build (16.4.0)

nuget packages, there is no more the exception. The project is loaded successfully.

Maybe, it will help someone more.

Comment: I have your same case and your solution doesn't fix it for me. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

- Add a `PackageReference` to `Microsoft.Build.Locator`.
- In a function which gets invoked before any function that uses any `Microsoft.Build` types, (and it must be a separate function,) invoke `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();` This magical incantation will set all the magic right.
- Create an instance of `ProjectOptions`
- Add an instance of `GlobalProperties` to it.
- Add a property "SolutionDir" with value `solutionFilePath + "\\"`
- Create your `Project` via a function that accepts `ProjectOptions`, for example `Project.FromFile()`.