# Why does loading a Xamarin Android .csproj into a Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project throw InvalidPropectFileException due to missing .targets file?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, project

I am attempting to open a Xamarin Android .csproj file in a .NET 5.0 console application using an instance of `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project`. Additionally I have also attempted to do the same with a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project.

The code for loading is:

```
var fileName = @"C:\Users\vchel\source\repos\BlankAndroid\BlankAndroid\BlankAndroid.csproj";
var project = new global::Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(fileName, null, null, new ProjectCollection());
```

When I attempt to instantiate the `Project` object, I get the following exception:

```
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: 
The imported project "C:\Users\vchel\source\repos\ProjectLoadTest\ProjectLoadTest\bin\Debug\net5.0\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found.
Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Users\vchel\source\repos\ProjectLoadTest\ProjectLoadTest\bin\Debug\net5.0\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\vchel\source\repos\BlankAndroid\BlankAndroid\BlankAndroid.csproj
```

The Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets file referenced in the error above appears in the .csproj that I am loading as shown in the following snippet:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
```

Notice that the .csproj references the Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targtets file with the `$(MSBuildExtensionPath)` prefix, but at runtime this is swapped with the location of the running console application .exe rather than

The Android project which I am attempting to load opens correctly in Visual Studio and compiles/runs with no problems.

Why does this Android project open without any problems in Visual Studio, yet it fails when attempting to open in a `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` object?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I've actually run into this same problem before, but it wasn't on an Android project so I'll keep this question here to address Android-specific issues.

The problem in general is discussed here:

[How to Load .csproj file into .NET Core 3.0 using MSBuild NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383581/how-to-load-csproj-file-into-net-core-3-0-using-msbuild-nuget?rq=1)

The summary is - the .target files are separate from the nuget packages being installed, and it seems like the Project class can't resolve $(MSBuildExtensionsPath). Therefore, to solve this problem the relevant .targets files should be added to the project and copied to the output (bin) folder.

On my machine, the original files can be found in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
```

I had to add the following files to my app. Notice they are added to the `Xamarin/Android/` folder:

[image]

Items can be marked as **Copy if newer**:

[image]